# Formtastic Problem, boolean field automatically checks itself after reporting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Have a boolean input in a formtastic form.

```
<%= f.input :legal, :as => :boolean, :input_html => { :checkbox_tag => false }, :label => "I Agree to the legal terms"  %>
```

If it isn't checked and the form is submitted, on reload (with all the error messages inline) the boolean field checks itself. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which has been corrected in 1.2.4 and in master.